# javascript regex fails with double quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this js

```
var race = {
    "id":           Number( matches[ i ].match( /gt5bspec\.selectEvent\("/(\d+/\d+)"\)/ )[ 1 ] ),
    "laps":         Number( matches[ i ].match( /<dd class="lap">.+?(\d+)/ )[ 1 ] ),
    "maxEntrants":  Number( matches[ i ].match( /entry_max.+?\/>(\d+)<\/dd>/ )[ 1 ] ),
    "time":         Number( matches[ i ].match( /common\/time\/(\d+)\.png/ )[ 1 ] ),
};
```

its failing SyntaxError: illegal character on the "id" line I am guessing due to the quotes in the expression.

here is an example string that is used for the search

```
<dl class="remote_event_list">  <dd class="course_logo"><img src="/common/images/gt5/remote_race/common/courselogo/ed2539fe892d2c52c42a440354e8e3d5.png" width="84"></dd>   <dd class="race_info_minute"><img src="/common/images/gt5/remote_race/common/time/20.png" width="80" height="54" alt=""></dd>   <dd class="entry_max"><img src="/common/images/gt5/remote_race/entry/icon_driver.png" width="20" />16</dd>  <dd class="lap"><span>Vuelta(s):</span>&nbsp;12 (en torno a 20 minutos)</dd>    <dd class="car_image">      <img src="/common/images/gt5/car/thumbnail/0a712318b3b8acc70daeb1ff71d40140.png" width="178" /> </dd>   <dd class="link"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick='gt5bspec.selectEvent("/116/1035200")' title="Abt Audi TT-R Touring Car '02 / Circuito de Madrid">&nbsp;</a></dd></dl>
```

I am trying to match the group 1 value of /116/1035200

Thanks

Comment: Quickly, it is due to the slashes: `"/(\d/\d+` . You must escape them with backslashes

Answer (score 3):

```
//-----------------------v
/gt5bspec\.selectEvent\("/(\d+/\d+)"\)/
```

I've marked the unescaped slash. If you want literal slash here, use `\/`.

Comment: Thanks changed it to    /gt5bspec\.selectEvent\("\/\d+\/(\d+)"\)/ and now works